# AJAE Documentclass and Author names

Tags: author

I am using the documentclass ajae.
It does not display the name of the authors nor their affiliations.
Can anyone help me? Many thanks.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{ajae}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx,caption,varwidth}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{abstract}
\title{XYXYXYXYXYXY}

\theauthor{AUTHOR1 \footnote{Institute} \footnote{Institute B} \footnote{Correspondence to } \and Author2\footnotemark[1] \footnotemark[2] }
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Acknowledgements}
\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome. Please add some code called "minimal workingexample" to the question, it would help a lot.

Comment: Thanks. Hint: You could also edit your question for adding changed. Could you provide a link for the ajae class?

Comment: I used this ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/tex/CTAN/biblio/bibtex/contrib/economic/erae-ex.tex

Comment: I found it here: [ajae.cls](ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/tex/CTAN/biblio/bibtex/contrib/economic/ajae.cls)

Answer (score 1):

The `ajae` class has a class option `author` to show the author names. The class also provides a command called `\affiliation` to add affiliation information. However, the class does not provide a mechanism to add multiple authors with different affiliations. You can do it manually (note that the command is `\author` and not `\theauthor`):

```
\documentclass[12pt,author]{ajae}
\usepackage{abstract}
\title{XYXYXYXYXYXY}

\author{AUTHOR X${}^1$ AUTHOR Y${}^2$}
\affiliation{${}^1$Institute A, ${}^2$Institute B} 
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Acknowledgements}
\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

---

Edit: alternatively, you can use the `authblk` package to specify something closer to your original approach. The `ajae` class defines double spacing (using the package `setspace`) which does not look good for multiple affiliation lines, therefore in the example below it is switched to single spacing for the title block.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,author]{ajae}
\usepackage{abstract}
\usepackage[noblocks]{authblk}
\title{XYXYXYXYXYXY}

\author[1, 2, 3]{AUTHOR1}
\author[1, 2]{AUTHOR2}
\affil[1]{Institute}
\affil[2]{Institute B}
\affil[3]{\textit{corresponding author}}
\begin{document}
\singlespacing
\maketitle
\doublespacing
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Acknowledgements}
\begin{abstract}
This is the abstract.
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]